# Booking roundtrip flights to Peru without knowing if tourist visa will be extended?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, tourist-visas, visa-extensions, visa-expiration

Here's my understanding of Peru's tourist visa:

- A normal tourist visa is good for 30-183 days
- The actual length of the initial visa varies (although I'm not sure why)
- The original visa can be extended with a visit to migrations, with a limit of 183 days in total from when you first entered the country.

BUT, in order to get your first tourist visa, you need to provide proof of your return flight.

So how do people who hope to stay longer than 30 days handle their flights? How do you book a return flight without knowing what day you'll return? I'd like to stay for 180 days, so should I get my return flight for 180 days after arrival and just pray that my visa extension gets approved?

I'm from the United States.

Comment: Note that the Peruvian government [says that US citizens traveling for tourism are generally given 90 days' entry](http://www.consulado.pe/Documents/visas/Requerimientos_de_visa_para_ciudadanos_extranjeros.pdf), while US citizens traveling for business must apply for a visa in advance. While it may be possible to stay longer than that, I wouldn't make plans that rely on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you book a return flight without knowing what day you'll return?

Book a flight with no cancelation fee, or a flight with no change fee, or buy some temporary onward ticket e.g. via https://onwardticket.com/

FYI [How do Peruvian officials determine how long tourists enduring Peru are allowed to stay?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168336/1810)

Comment: Wow, onwoardticket looks perfect!