# How do Peruvian officials determine how long US tourists entering Peru are allowed to stay?

Tags: us-citizens, tourist-visas, peru

I read on [Travel.state.gov international travel](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Peru.html):

> Your length of approved stay will be determined by border officials at the time of entry, and can range from 30 to 183 days. Extensions for tourists are usually not approved, and overstays result in fines.

How do Peruvian officials determine how long tourists entering Peru are allowed to stay? Assume the tourist is a US citizen.

Comment: From your itinerary and bookings?

Comment: From whatever side of the bed they got up that day?  Your demeanor when presenting to those officials?

Comment: From your Peruvian flute playing ability?

Comment: If my memory is working properly, they didn't ask me in 2016 how long I planned to stay, nor did they look at my tickets.  But maybe scanning my passport somehow gave them that information—that was one of the few trips where I actually had a return ticket.  But they also said nothing about length of stay.  The stamp in my passport doesn't contain any restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

My experience is from early 2022 at a land border. The official would ask people how long they planned to stay in Peru. Depending on how sensible/clear their answer was, they were at times grilled a bit more. It seemed that she then gave people the number of days people needed for their stated duration, padding/rounding a bit. In my sample of four, duration granted ranged from 60-90 days.